# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found for a link that I can open in my browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

```
Iurl = 'https://i7y3a6q5.stackpathcdn.com/media/14490/क-स-न.jpg?width=350&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first'

The above url might generate an error as not all of the characters in it are in Unicode format. So, here's the converted url:

https://i7y3a6q5.stackpathcdn.com/media/14490/%E0%A4%95-%E0%A4%B8-%E0%A4%A8.jpg?width=350&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first
```

> this is the url that is resulting in an error, it's a link to an image that I can open in my browser.

```
img = urllib.request.urlopen(Iurl)  # Downloading the image
```

> This is the statement which is generating the 404 error.
>   I tried the solutions provided on similar questions but none of them worked for me.
>    I need something like this as my output when I print my img
>   The ss contains the entire error stack trace
>   [image]

Comment: Unable to reproduce/ `img = request.urlopen('https://i7y3a6q5.stackpathcdn.com/media/14490/%E0%A4%95-%E0%A4%B8-%E0%A4%A8.jpg?width=350&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first')
` returns http status code 200 which is success

Comment: If you try printing the content of img it will still print Error 404, I tried this  method too. Here you won't receive any errors externally but you won't get any content either. It should return an object that contains that image.

Comment: can you post the actual error

Comment: <Response [404]>
This is what I got when I tried printing the img variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have given cannot be reproduced, you should show your code block and a copy of the error / stack trace. I have constructed a simple example of what you say your trying to do it and works fine for me.

```py
import urllib.request

with open("img.jpg", 'wb') as image:
    Iurl = 'https://i7y3a6q5.stackpathcdn.com/media/14490/%E0%A4%95-%E0%A4%B8-%E0%A4%A8.jpg?width=350&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first'
    img = urllib.request.urlopen(Iurl)
    print(f"Fetching url {Iurl}, HTTP Response Code: {img.msg}({img.status})")
    image.write(img.read())
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
Fetching url https://i7y3a6q5.stackpathcdn.com/media/14490/%E0%A4%95-%E0%A4%B8-%E0%A4%A8.jpg?width=350&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first, HTTP Response Code: OK(200)
```

This creates a file in the dir where my code ran from. When I open the file the image is there.

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much this worked. But I couldn't understand how? i mean I'm practically doing the same thing, except the print statement that you mentioned in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try this. It returns a 200 response and was able to print the content to console.

```py
import requests

url = 'https://i7y3a6q5.stackpathcdn.com/media/14490/क-स-न.jpg?width=350&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first'

img = requests.get(url)
print(img.content)
```

You can write as this if you want it downloaded on your machine

```py
import requests
import shutil

url = 'https://i7y3a6q5.stackpathcdn.com/media/14490/क-स-न.jpg?width=350&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first'

with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as output_file, requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, output_file)
```

Comment: <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x03A536D0>
This is the type of content I need, this response object contains the data of that image.

Comment: I get the content printed in bytes to my console. Is this what you got when you printed img.content?

Comment: Yes, so do I need to cast the content? If yes, then how can I do that? Thanks for your help.